# List of Lua commands/statements to watch out?

Tags: security, lua

I'm making a moddable game and thinking about using Lua as the language for my players to write their own scripts.

But like any programming language, Lua bound to have some "loopholes" for not-so-nice users to do bad things.

I'm new to Lua, so I don't really know what Lua "can" do.

I did a little reasearch online and found that `Metatable` and `ob.exit` could be used for doing bad things, is there any other things?

Could somebody please be so kind and give me a list of the things I should watch out and block it (maybe by replacing it with empty string)?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Search for Lua sandbox

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua's built-in `math`, `string`, and `table` libraries will *always* be safe. `coroutine` is also safe, and extremely useful to some advanced lua programmers.

There are some other, not-so-safe libraries lua loads in by default (which you can easily disable)

- `os` lets you execute commands, and do other nasty things. However, `os.time` and `os.date` are useful functions, so keep those in.
- `io` allows you to read- and edit- any file on the computer. Probably best to leave it out.
- `debug` allows you to "reflect" on the program. This means that the program can edit certain parts about itself, and can be unwanted. It's a safe bet that user programs won't need this. Ever.

Instead of replacing something with an empty string, you can always replace it with `setfenv` (Lua 5.1), like so:

```lua
   local badCode = readFile("./code.lua")
   local Func = loadstring(badCode)
   setfenv(Func, {
       -- If we leave nothing here, then the script will not be able to access any global variable.
       -- It's perfectly sandboxed. But let's give it some stuff:
       print = print, pcall = pcall, pairs = pairs, ipairs = ipairs, error = error, string = string, table = table, math = math, coroutine = coroutine,
       -- Now, let's give it some functions that *could* be useful, from an otherwise sandboxed library
       os = {
           time = os.time,
           date = os.date,
           clock = os.clock,
       },
       -- All of these are "kind of" useful to the program.

   })
   -- Now that Func is properly sandboxed, let's run it!
   Func()
   -- This is how you should treat user code.
```